# Do not reschedule Quartz stateful job

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz v1.x stateful job. The repeat interval is let's say 1 minute. The job itself typically terminates within a second, but it might happen that it lasts long, let's say 5 minutes. The scheduler prevents parallel run, but when the long running job finishes, it starts it again over and over again those, which were missed during the long running job. In this example, 5 other runs will be scheduled right after the long execution finishes. What I want is to make the scheduler "forget" the missed starts. E.g. if a job starts at 12:00 and finished at 12:05, then simply omit the runs at 12:01, 12:02, 12:03, 12:04, and depending on the exact finish, even 12:05. Is this somehow possible?

I need stateful job for preventing the parallel execution. Stateless job with proper annotation is not an option, because we are using Quartz version 1.x. I already tried playing around with the misfire policies (e.g. `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING`), but it seems that these are not intended for such situations. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Quartz 2.x? I ask because if MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING did not have the desired effect, you may be facing some nasty bug in a very old Quartz code base. Note: latest Quartz 1.x version (1.8.6) was released on 12/Jan/2012.

Comment: @Csaba MISFIRE should be suitable for you, even in Quartz v1.x. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625158/3883957. If something isn't working properly, maybe there is a bug as Jan noted.